# Charset PHP convert not completely working

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

So we've got a text file that we're trying to upload to a database. We've managed to do that. However, the text file comes from Microsoft Office so it's got a load of horrible tags in. We convert the file by using `mb_convert_encoding($content, "UTF-8", "UTF-16");`

This allows us to strip the nasty  tags etc.

However, even after conversion we are still getting characters like `⁂`, instead of "B. and `†` instead of closing smart quotes (from office).

Is there any conversion method people have found that works? Please note I have also tried iconv and utf8_convert.

I've also had a search through other posts and I am yet to find the solution.

Thanks

Comment: What is your result with iconv? for me is the best solution

Comment: iconv doesnt seem to be working at all! it doesnt output anything

Comment: scratch that - echo $content = iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $content); shows a load of chinese characters!

Comment: did you check if source data are OK? // maybe mb_detect_encoding()

Comment: I did. The data source says ASCII and UTF-8. not sure how reliable it is - i think it's getting it wrong. i've tried converting from ASCII to UTF-8 too, no working for that either!

Comment: What kind of "tags" does the file have, do you mean html or xml tags or something else?